# How does this picture called?

Tags: soft-question

Some time ago I saw this in my teacher's room. She called this picture in honor of some scientists (Lagrange,Lie or Liouville, or some other, but I don't remember). Please, name  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bs6s.jpg) picture. Thank you!

Comment: I think the tag (big-picture) is not entirely appropriate. You may want (soft-question). The picture looks like the [lorenz attractor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorenzAttractor.html)

Comment: Perhaps it is Lorentz?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a picture of the [lorenz attractor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorenzAttractor.html):

[image: Lorenz Attractor]